# Save embedded files from .xls document (Apache POI)

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

I would like to save all attached files from an Excel (xls/HSSF) without extension. 
I've been trying for a long time now, and I really don't know if this is even possible. I also tried Apache Tika, but I don't want to use Tika for this, because I need POI for other tasks, anyway.

I tried the sample code from the [Busy Developers Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Embedded), but this does not extract files in the old office format (doc, ppt, xls). And it throws an Error when trying to create `new SlideShow(new HSLFSlideShow(dn, fs))` Error: `(Remove argument to match HSLFSlideShow(dn))`

My actual code is:

```
public static void saveEmbeddedXLS(InputStream fis_param, String embDIR) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{
    //HSSF - XLS

    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Starting Embedded Search in xls...");

    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis_param);//create FileSystem using fileInputStream
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

    for (HSSFObjectData obj : workbook.getAllEmbeddedObjects()) {

        System.out.println("Objects : "+ obj.getOLE2ClassName());//the OLE2 Class Name of the object
        String oleName = obj.getOLE2ClassName();//Document Type

        DirectoryNode dn = (DirectoryNode) obj.getDirectory();//get Directory Node  

        //Trying to create an input Stream with the embedded document, argument of createDocumentInputStream should be: String; Where/How can I get this correct parameter for the function?
        InputStream is = dn.createDocumentInputStream(dn);//This line is incorrect! How can I do i correctly? 

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("embDIR" + i);//Outputfilepath + Number

        IOUtils.copy(is, fos);//FileInputStream > FileOutput Stream (save File without extension)
        i++;
       } 
    }
```

So my simple question is: 
**Is it possible to save ALL attachments from an xls file without any extension (as simple as possible)?** And can any one provide me a solution? Many Thanks!

Comment: Does the Apache Tika CLI App in `-z` mode do what you need? (The code for that is open source and fairly easy to read!)

Comment: Tika uses POI to do it's magic.

Comment: @Gagravarr No it doesn't! I know that Tika uses POI... Isn't it possible in my suggested way?

Comment: If you just want to save the file, why are you trying to load the powerpoint or word files into POI? Why not just stream the contents out to disk as-is?

Comment: @Gagravarr I don't know what you mean... Basically if there are any attachments in this excel file, i need to save them in the easiest possible way. Can you give me an example to understand what you mean?

Comment: The example code you linked to is for loading them, not saving them. You've also posted a bunch of code without explaining what doesn't work with it. You haven't said if the Tika App logic works or not. We're not mind readers here!